# Unresolved Proxy error when installing Xtext Plugin

Tags: xtext

When exporting my Xtext-Plugin as a deployable feature, I can install it in another Eclipse IDE, but whenever I open a file `test.mydsl` I get this error-message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unresolved proxy http://www.Mydsl.myorg#//Model. Make sure the EPackage has been registered.
```

I read somewhere that a possible cause could be the `plugin.xml` and `plugin.xml_gen` files being out-of-sync, but this is not the case here...

Btw I am using `Xtext 2.11`

Comment: does it work with a newly created mydsl project? does your project have warnings in build.properties? does the jar file contain the mydsl.ecore?

Comment: Yeah, there were errors in build.properties. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have any warnings or errors in your projects build.properties so that everything can get packaged properly